# How do I convert one value into a corresponding one from a conversion table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, find-replace

I apologize if the phrasing of my question didn't make much sense, but hopefully my explanation will help.

Say I have a dataframe, `ex`, which looks like this:

```
  geneID sample1 sample2
1      1      18       2
2     10       6      17
3    100       9      12
```

And a corresponding table, `convtab`, that looks like this:

```
  geneID genesymbol
1      1       A1BG
2     10       NAT2
3    100        ADA
```

The goal here is that for every geneID in `ex`, if it matches a value in `convtab$geneID`, replace it with the corresponding value from `convtab$genesymbol` in the same row.

For example, the value in [1,1] of `ex`, 1, would be replaced with A1BG.

While I could do it manually with this example set, my actual set of data is much larger so I would have no chance of changing the values manually.

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: `ex$geneID <- convtab$genesymbol[match(ex$geneID, convtab$geneID)]`

Comment: FYI, you said *"if it matches"*, suggesting that it may not always match. If there is a missing match, then that code will be incomplete, rendering your not-matched IDs as `NA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this can be done as:

```
 ex$geneID <- convtab$genesymbol[match(ex$geneID, convtab$geneID)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`you could left_join the data.frames:

```r
library(dplyr)

ex %>%
  left_join(rep, by=("geneID")) %>%
  select(-geneID, geneID=genesymbol)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  sample1 sample2 geneID
    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
1      18       2 A1BG  
2       6      17 NAT2  
3       9      12 ADA
```